Can I connect an "Ubuntu online account" to a nextcloud instance hosted at an .onion address (via proxy.pac or port 9050)?
My Nextcloud instance is accessible through the tor network via a .onion address. I would like to connect an "Ubuntu Online Account" to it via the system settings so I can see my contacts, calendar, and tasks in the respective gnome/ubuntu apps. I already have the tor proxy service running system-wide.
I am able to access my server with apps like bitwarden by adding the flag --proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050, and can connect thunderbird to it by directing it to a proxy.pac file downloaded locally on my computer. I just don't know how to set up the ubuntu online accounts for it.
